# entire JS folder not loading in a WP theme

Tags: php, functions, json

[image]

When I include this function ins single.php the entire JS folder doesn't download in browser.

```
  add_action('wp_ajax_myfilter', 'misha_filter_function');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_myfilter', 'misha_filter_function');
function misha_filter_function(){
            $args = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' => 'id',
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'posts_per_page' => 10,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
        );

        // for taxonomies / categories
        if( isset( $_POST['categoryfilter'] ) )
            $args['tax_query'] = array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'category',
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'terms' => $_POST['categoryfilter'],
                    'post_type' => 'post',
                    'posts_per_page' => 10,
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                )
            );
        // the query
        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    ?>
    <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
        <!-- the loop -->
        <ul class="sidebar-flex">
        <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <li class="sbox sbox4">
                <div class="simg"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'large') ?></div>
                <div class="stext3">
                    <h4><?php $categories = get_the_category();
                    if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {
                      echo '<a class="themecolor" href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $categories[0]->term_id ) ) . '">'  . esc_html( $categories[0]->name ) . '</a>';
                    } ?></h4>
                    <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                </div>
            </li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        </ul>
        <!-- end of the loop -->
        <!-- <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?> -->
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php die(); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

This behaviour is very strange? what could be the reason?

Comment: Nothing in your functions file is loading a script. I'm not clear on what you're expecting to happen.

Comment: Scripts are already [loaded](https://www.screencast.com/t/Yu1zESLrBaVN), but as soon as the above-mentioned functions is used the whole JS folder is not loaded in the browser may be die() is causing an issue.

Comment: There's nothing in that code that would cause scripts not to load. That function isn't even going run. Ever. Why are you hooking AJAX in single.php? How is the function going to be hooked when single.php isn't loaded on AJAX requests.

Comment: `<?php die(); ?>` → But as soon as  I delete this everything works ok.

Comment: Are you actually running `misha_filter_function()` somewhere else in the template. That would cause the problem (and the bigger problem of your whole footer not loading, not just your scripts).

Comment: misha_filter_function() → defined in functions.php and then called in single.php

Comment: Right ok, yes `die()` will cause the site to stop loading anything after the function. You need 2 functions: One to output what you want to output, and one that outputs the first function and then `die()`. Use the first one on its own inside the template, and then hook the 2nd one into  AJAX.

Comment: Also: Don't use `POST` requests for *getting* data. Use `GET`. Those words mean what they say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `die()`. You can't `die()` inside a template or it will stop the entire site loading at that point. If you looked closer you'd notice that it wasn't just the JS folder that wasn't loading, it was the whole footer.

You need to separate you code into 2 functions. One that outputs the HTML you want to output, and a second function that runs the first function and then dies.

So have the first function:

```
function misha_filter_function() {
    // Query posts, output loop, etc. etc.
}
```

Then a 2nd function, just for AJAX, that calls the first function then `die()`:

```
function misha_filter_function_ajax() {
    misha_filter_function();
    die();
}
```

Then hook the *second* function for AJAX:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_myfilter', 'misha_filter_function_ajax' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_myfilter', 'misha_filter_function_ajax' );
```

The first function could also just be a template. Then in the AJAX function and template you could just use `get_template_part()`:

```
function misha_filter_function_ajax() {
    get_template_part( 'partials/filter' ); // theme-directory/partials/filter.php
    die();
}
```

Also, you should be using `GET` and `$_GET` for this use-case. `POST` should be used for sending data to a server to be processed, and usually involves updating or creating a resource. `GET` should be used for retrieving (*getting*) data. You're simply retrieving HTML, so should use the `GET` method.